# Create a google map, using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

my name is Eleni, this is the first time posting here!
These days try to create a **google map** by using **knockout.js**.
This map should have a list with locations at the left side, creating by knockout, 
which I have already create, but also needs when the user clicks on the same list,
the marker of the map which is about the selected location to appears and all others disappear, also with knockout.

I have read a lot about this but can't figure it out guys, some of the resources i used:
Knockout : The "click" binding
[connecting list view in knockout.js with map markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272535/connecting-list-view-in-knockout-js-with-map-markers)

if anyone can have a look in my github repo:
https://github.com/Heleni/maps_udacity
and help, I ll appreciated a lot!!!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: both link shows as a not found page, would you mind putting your code in your question?

Comment: hi, thanks for the notification, i just upload the right link and works fine right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found out,

So here is you knockout js code for what you are doing.

Tell me if that works :

```
function Coord(lat, ing) {
var self = this;
self.lat = ko.observable(lat);
self.ing = ko.observable(ing);
}

function Place(title, lat, ing, address) {
    var self = this;
    self.title = title;
    self.address = address;
    self.coords = ko.observable(new Coord(lat,ing));
    self.visible = ko.observable(true);

    //create a function to make the list of locations clikable
     self.myList = function() {
        map.setZoom(18);
        map.panTo({lat: self.coords().lat(), lng: self.coords().ing()});
        //map.setCenter(markers[title].getPosition());
    }; 
}

function LocationsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.query = ko.observable('');

    self.places = ko.observableArray([
        new Place("Ble Cafe-Restaurant", 40.632286, 22.944743, "Street: Agias Sofias 19, 54623"),
        new Place("Olympion Bar-Restaurant", 40.632744, 22.941767, "Street: Aristotelous Square 10, 54623"),
        new Place("Olive and Oregon Restaurant", 40.634679, 22.943193, "Street: Aristotelous Square 10, 54623"),
        new Place("Mojo Cafe", 40.631824, 22.940958, "Aristotelous 4, 54623"),
        new Place("Seven Seas Restaurant", 40.633300, 22.939356, "Kalapothaki 10, 54624"),
        new Place("Varelakia Gyros", 40.574634, 22.949332, "Street: Riga Fereou 97, 56728"),
    ]);

    self.search = function() {
      for(var x in self.places()) {
        if( self.query() != '' && self.places()[x].title.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query().toLowerCase()) < 0) {
           self.places()[x].visible(false);
        }else{
            self.places()[x].visible(true);
        }
      }
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new LocationsViewModel());
```

I let you find out where to put that.

And here is the html :

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Find Cafes and Restaurants in Thessaloniki City</h1>
<div class="myList">
  <form action="#">
    <!-- create search box for user's input -->
    <input placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="q" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off">
  </form>
  <div class="content">
    <!-- display the list -->
      <!--add the click event here to make the list clickable -->
    <ul data-bind="template: {name:'place', foreach:places}">

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the template in script balise

```
<li data-bind="visible: visible"><strong data-bind="text: title, click: myList"></strong></li>
```

I have updated the code for the search function.
It includes a new ko.observable in the place object, a new function in LocationsViewModel and a new tag in the html.

Comment: thanks again, i just recreate the project with your suggestions, i don't know if is my bad but the titles of the list are not clickable and not have the ability to appear a marker per title.
I am going to post my code for you to see.

Comment: here you can see my new script file
https://github.com/Heleni/maps_udacity

Comment: I edited the code for place and coord and I will add in a second the new html file you need to use. 

Your search method doesn't work either but I think you will be able to find out.

Comment: maybe this helps us little bit more: this is the work i need my list to do:
https://codepen.io/dmoojunk/pen/KzXGKq

Comment: This actually what I have on my machine with the code up there. Well except the cat's and text on select. 

This is still doesn't work for you ? Can i commit on your git eventually ?

Comment: yes, you can commit or post the code here
cant see what i am doing wrong

Comment: I can't commit because i don't have the push permissions.

The wrong part here is in the index.html files here.

The click chould be in the template. Not on the foreach. You want every point to be clickable separately.

Comment: sorry i am new to the gitHub so i don't know it so well
you mean this part is wrong:
`code`
  <div class="content">
        <!-- display the list -->
          <!--add the click event here to make the list clicable -->
        <ul data-bind="template: {name:'place', foreach:places}">

        </ul>
      </div>

Comment: you need :
<ul data-bind="template: {name:'place', foreach:places}">
</ul>

And 

<script data-proofer-ignore type="text/html" id="place">
    <li><strong data-bind="text: title , click: myList"></strong></li>
  </script>

you can see that the "click: myList" is in the second part.

Comment: oh gosh it works!!!
just it has broken the part which you can select the area you want by typing!
thanks so much!

Comment: Yeah this part is broken because the search method shoud work with another list and not the same as the first one otherwise you won't be able to refullfil it.  
I'm glad thar work for you. now, if you want your point to be selected you have to add a function to select the google marker you want and then trigger the click like that :

var marker = FindMarker(self.title); //find the marker
new google.maps.event.trigger( marker, 'click' ); //select the marker

And add that part in the function myList.

Comment: i don't know how to make this right now, but i think i ll figure it out, thank you very much for your help and you spending time on my problem, i appreciate a lot!

Comment: No problem, DO not hesitate to go it again. 
It the first time I help someone and it found it fun :)

Comment: hi again! hope i am not bother you! you helpt me the other time a lot and i would like to ask you if is it possible to advise me for one more time something!
how can i make myList at the left decrease the titles  when user types in the search box https://github.com/Heleni/google_maps

Comment: Hi again, i just cloned back your git. I will look at your search function but i though we manage to resolve the gmap problem. Here when i click on a link, it doesn't how the point on the map, is that normal ?

Comment: hi!! nice to hear you again!when you click a title it drives to a marker, you had helpt me to make project works like this!https://github.com/Heleni/google_maps

Comment: I updated the post with the search method. But i guess it's simple javascript. I will refer you to that knockout tutorial about collections and arrays :

http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections

Comment: thanks again for your help! i think i ll figure it out how the search box should work from http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections.
have a nice day :)

Comment: you have the solution in the code of the answer. i corrected it.

Comment: i see that you made list work perfect! i meant that i ll found out how the search box needs to work. the user right now can't type in and the list be decreased. i am sorry if i am missing something, i did refresh my code with your new one, you can see here: https://github.com/Heleni/google_maps

Comment: i have create how the search box exactly should work, https://github.com/Heleni/live-search-list
but the problem is that when i put that in my project everything are broken!!!

Comment: Come back to you original project : github.com/Heleni/google_maps
I found what the proble is. It's your binding of the event.
You should bind your searchBox this way : <input placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="q" data-bind="value: query, event: { keyup: search }" autocomplete="off">
But i still have a problem. I still have a problem with that solution. it works only when i put a breack point in the developper tool of chrome... i don't know why.

Comment: no problem, you have already helpt me so much, appreciated a lot!
 Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your github link is incorrect and lead to a 404.

But in knockout, you can easily have a list of all your points for the gmap that you provide on the left side.
And when you click on it you refresh your map with only that point.

Knockout's binding make that refresh for you.

I think the knockout's tutorial will show you how.

Good luck with that,

JBO

Comment: just upload the link and works right now. I have watch all knockout's tutors and they don't shows how to use knockout into a google map, so for someone using first time knockout is frustrated.

Comment: Ok,  I have donwloaded your project and i will try to help you. 

For what i can see, you are not using it correctly. 

Well let's explain myself :

function myList(){ line 229 of your script is using the title object of you model. But the function isn't in the model so title is unknown. 

You must create a knockout object that will contains the title and at least the functions you want to work with for that object.

Then you include a list of that object in your viewmodel. 

In your html that means you iterate over the list in knockout and your click will then work.

Comment: i am working already on what you said,appreciated a lot your suggestions,
would be easy for you to post the code corrected?
 thanks anyway for your time.